# Which version for correct Nvidia setup for Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, cuda

Trying to install latest Nvidia/CUDA after update, the drivers tool points to 340.108 (proprietary, tested) but I try installing cuda Ubuntu packages... Now I get

```
$ sudo apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libnvidia-compute-460
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libnvidia-compute-460
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
9 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/21.8 MB of archives.
After this operation, 102 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 460152 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libnvidia-compute-460_460.39-0ubuntu0.20.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libnvidia-compute-460:amd64 (460.39-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libnvidia-compute-460_460.39-0ubuntu0.20.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-ml.so', which is also in package nvidia-340 340.108-0ubuntu5.20.04.1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libnvidia-compute-460_460.39-0ubuntu0.20.04.1_amd64.deb
```

I'd prefer 460 if that is allowed but why is this conflicting - do I need to remove and re install as I have on system that had an issue with older Nvidia?

To be clear, "nvidia-cuda-toolkit" requres libnvidia-compute-460 on Ubuntu focal 20.04, but the driver installed in the tools is nvidia-340 ("proprietary, tested" in the Additional drivers tab), the only choice other than Nouveau open source driver. Why?

Comment: I'm just guessing here...  But based on what you've shown, it looks like the package you're installing has a file that will overwrite something that `nvidia-340` had installed.  Is it possible to explicitly uninstall `nvidia-340`?  Is `libnvidia-ml.so` a file or a symbolic link?  If it was my system, I'd probably play around and try renaming `libnvidia-ml.so`.  That's something you can try and if that doesn't work, quickly rename it back before progressing further...

Comment: Had to remove various ones breaking: ```sudo apt remove libcuinj64-10.1 libnvidia-compute-455 libnvidia-ml-dev libnvidia-compute* nvidia-cuda* python3-pycu* nvidia-profiler nvidia-visual* thin-client-config*```

Comment: I presume this means you've solved your problem?  If so, that's good to hear!

Answer (score 0):

Possible workarounds:

- after the install fails, can repair it with DPKG "--force-overwrite":

  `apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-overwrite" install --fix-broken`
- as an extra flag to the install command-line:

  `apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-overwrite" install nvidia-cuda-toolkit`

It seems possible to provide the same `Dpkg::Options` param on the command-line of `apt` as well as of `apt-get`, whichever tool you prefer to use.